# html5 sliding independent page transition for desktop website

Tags: html, transition, sliding

I am trying to program a website with multiple independent pages and I would like to use the slide transition effect between pages as it can be done with the jquery mobile Framework but WITHOUT using this one. My goal is to make a desktop web site and not a mobile app.

The fluidity and the speed of execution are my objectives. I saw that you can use the jQuery Easing plugin (version 1.3) but I'm not able to place this code for having a fluid transition effects between independent pages.

I intended to do this transition page effect with the TerrenceRyan.com solution but it doesn't work correctly.

I don't want to do a navigation with jquery anchor or hidden divs placed in a long one page, but many independent pages that arrive at their click sliding.

To give you an example of what I am trying to achieve, here are some links:

http://www.craigandkarl.com/
http://www.ultranoir.com/

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an example we can look at? It's a bit difficult to determine the exact question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is key and you don't want to use jQuery maybe have a look at the new [greensock javascript library](http://www.greensock.com/tag/javascript/)

They have a test page which shows that it performs really well against other similar libraries:

[speed test page](http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html)

I have been using their AS2, AS3 engine for flash for many years now and if the JS version is nearly as good, then I'm sure it will be of use to you.